# Successor of dbms_random.random

Tags: oracle, random, plsql, oracle12c

I was typing a question a problem with the package/function `dbms_random.random` and found, [that the usage is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_random.htm#ARPLS67499).

What is the successor for generating a random number?

Googling for [oracle 12c random](https://www.google.de/search?q=Successor%20of%20dbms_random.random) only brings dbms_random and the documentation gives no hint.

Comment: Hi, you just use the other functions e.g. .value .string etc. The most useful reference guide I use for dbms_random is https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dbms_random#random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are confused with `DBMS_RANDOM` package with the function `RANDOM` and the `RANDOM` is deprecated not the `DBMS_RANDOM` package.

The `RANDOM` function was deprecated in favor of other functions like `SEED`, `NORMAL`,`VALUE`,`STRING` etc.

[Summary of DBMS_RANDOM Subprograms](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_random.htm#ARPLS67493)

Answer (score 1):

The deprecated `RANDOM` function in `DBMS_RANDOM` returns an integer value from -2147483648 to 2147483648. To obtain this same range using `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` you'd use

```
TRUNC((DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE-0.5)*POWER(2, 32))
```

Best of luck.